Ubuntu 22.04 with 6.9 kernel is causing partial upgrade problem
I have just updated my kernel to 6.9 to make the speakers of my laptop work properly (DELL XPS15).
Now the Ubuntu updater is showing an error and asking for a "Partial Upgrade". When I tried, however, it was blocked asking me to stop the kernel I just installed, so that it can be removed. Is there any workaround to fix this? I'd like to keep the kernel as I can enjoy a decent sound for the first time. Forgive me if this is a naive question, I don't know if the kernel is tied to updates and I'd be happy to get any advice on how to proceed.
Edit:
If I understand this correctly, this kernel is not supported yet, and won't be in the near future. So I either accept this (lack of updates/support) or roll back to my previous one. Moving to Ubuntu 24.04 won't help either.

@user535733 No this is not an XY problem. The speaker's problem was solved only after a long search, thanks to the work of good people who patched Linux kernels. You can see the issue yourself and appreciate that no other solution was found by many people with a lot of knowledge on the topic: https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/4624

@OrganicMarble I might have got this wrong, but I think Ubuntu 24 is not getting 6.9 until late this year. That's what my search results reported.

How did you update the kernel? Please use the mainline tool for that https://github.com/bkw777/mainline

Please run sudo apt update and then run sudo apt full-upgrade and post the full output of the last command

Thank you @ArchismanPanigrahi , yes I used mainline. Running your commands worked, and now everything is updated. It removed the 6.9 headers, but I rebooted and I am still on 6.9. It was my misunderstanding to think that would cause the kernel itself to be removed. Again thank you for pointing me the solution

"I think Ubuntu 24 is not getting 6.9 until late this year" Ubuntu 24.04 (the accurate version number is important) won't get 6.9 at all. HWE users will get the same kernel as Ubuntu 24.10, currently kernel 6.10...but it might change. That will occur around January 2025.

Can someone explain their downvote?

It turned out that the solution is to run sudo apt update and sudo apt full-upgrade, so that all the kernel header files are properly configured.

Can someone explain their downvote?
